# How to insert a grid in PDF using aspose.pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspose

How can I insert a gridview/ gridview content into PDF ?

I am generating a pdf using aspose.pdf. My Page has a gridview.The column number shall remain constant in my grid but rows may vary.

How can I insert that grid content into my PDF file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add it to your paragraph like so:

```
Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Table tab1 = new Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Table();
sec1.Paragraphs.Add(tab1);
```

To the `Table` you can add `Row` objects etc. Check out the ASPOSE PDF online documentation at http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/aspose-pdf-generator-articles.html.

Good luck!